# Searching for nodes in the network

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Let consider the network ('graph'):

```
q1 = {{6545, 1044}, {6546, 1044}, {6536, 1044}, {6537, 1043}, {6529, 
1044}, {6530, 1043}, {6528, 1044}, {6529, 1044}, {6528, 
1044}, {6529, 1043}, {6527, 1044}, {6528, 1044}, {6522, 
1044}, {6523, 1043}, {6544, 1045}, {6545, 1044}, {6535, 
1045}, {6536, 1044}, {6526, 1045}, {6527, 1044}, {6521, 
1045}, {6522, 1044}, {6543, 1046}, {6544, 1045}, {6534, 
1046}, {6535, 1045}, {6525, 1046}, {6526, 1045}, {6521, 
1046}, {6522, 1045}, {6520, 1046}, {6521, 1045}, {6517, 
1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6542, 1047}, {6543, 1048}, {6542, 
1047}, {6543, 1046}, {6535, 1047}, {6536, 1046}, {6534, 
1047}, {6535, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6534, 1047}, {6533, 
1047}, {6534, 1046}, {6532, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6531, 
1047}, {6532, 1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6526, 1048}, {6524, 
1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6524, 1047}, {6525, 1046}, {6520, 
1047}, {6521, 1046}, {6519, 1047}, {6520, 1047}, {6519, 
1047}, {6520, 1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6519, 1047}, {6518, 
1047}, {6518, 1048}, {6549, 1048}, {6550, 1049}, {6543, 
1048}, {6544, 1049}, {6532, 1048}, {6533, 1049}, {6532, 
1048}, {6533, 1047}, {6530, 1048}, {6531, 1047}, {6526, 
1048}, {6527, 1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6524, 1047}, {6518, 
1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6550, 1049}, {6551, 1050}, {6548, 
1049}, {6549, 1048}, {6547, 1049}, {6548, 1049}, {6545, 
1049}, {6546, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6545, 1049}, {6543, 
1049}, {6544, 1049}, {6542, 1049}, {6543, 1049}, {6539, 
1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6538, 1049}, {6539, 1049}, {6537, 
1049}, {6538, 1049}, {6536, 1049}, {6537, 1049}, {6533, 
1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6529, 1049}, {6530, 1048}, {6529, 
1049}, {6529, 1050}, {6527, 1049}, {6528, 1050}, {6522, 
1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6518, 
1049}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 1050}, {6551, 1051}, {6546, 
1050}, {6547, 1049}, {6543, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6541, 
1050}, {6542, 1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6541, 1050}, {6535, 
1050}, {6536, 1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6535, 1050}, {6529, 
1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6528, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6521, 
1050}, {6522, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6520, 1051}, {6551, 
1051}, {6551, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6543, 1050}, {6529, 
1051}, {6529, 1052}, {6520, 1051}, {6521, 1052}, {6520, 
1051}, {6521, 1050}, {6517, 1051}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 
1052}, {6552, 1052}, {6541, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6529, 
1052}, {6530, 1053}, {6521, 1052}, {6522, 1053}, {6540, 
1053}, {6541, 1052}, {6538, 1053}, {6539, 1054}, {6531, 
1053}, {6532, 1054}, {6530, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6530, 
1053}, {6531, 1053}, {6522, 1053}, {6522, 1054}, {6539, 
1054}, {6540, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 
1055}, {6534, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1056}, {6532, 
1055}, {6533, 1055}, {6521, 1055}, {6522, 1054}, {6533, 
1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6521, 1055}, {6534, 
1057}, {6535, 1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6534, 1057}, {6519, 
1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6518, 1058}, {6519, 1057}, {6517, 
1059}, {6518, 1058}};
q2 = Partition[q1, 2];
q3 = Map[Line@# &, q2];
lines = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Opacity[0.7], q3}, ImageSize -> 500];
k2 = ListPlot[Take[q1], PlotStyle -> Black];
graph = Show[lines, k2]
```

[image]

Let's draw a node:

```
pointX = RandomChoice[q1];
```

Let `pointX = {6534, 1050};

How to find specific graph nodes at distance 'r'?

Searched nodes have a degree greater than 2.

An example for 'r1=8' and 'r=4' is shown below:
[image]

We are only looking for the number of these points!

You can see that:

- There are 4 such points at a distance of 'r1'.
- There is 1 such point at a distance 'r2'.

Comment: Extract the coordinates (`GraphEmbedding`) and use `Nearest`? Does this work for you?

Comment: 'GraphEmbedding' does not work for 'Graphics[] ', unfortunately :(

Comment: In addition, the conversion to the graph will change its topology (shape).

Comment: @ralph just use region intersection on disk and points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216651/531) is great (especially the `Manipulate`!), but this problem gives me a chance to show off a couple under-appreciated Mathematica functions I really like, so I'll take a crack at it too.

First, let's do the work necessary to actually turn this into a Mathematica `Graph` object. We need to start with a list of **unique** points.

```
points = DeleteDuplicates[q1];
```

It will be convenient to refer to them by an index, which [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) is **almost** perfect for. However, it returns a bunch of singleton lists, while we want integers.

```
pointIndex = First /@ PositionIndex[points];
```

Going the other way will also help!

```
vertexCoordinates = AssociationMap[Reverse, pointIndex];
```

With `pointIndex`, we can easily construct a list of edges using [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html); no need for an extra `Partition` step:

```
edges = BlockMap[Apply[UndirectedEdge], pointIndex /@ q1, 2];
```

Now we can represent the graph as a, well, graph instead of just a collection of lines:

```
graph = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Normal@vertexCoordinates]
```

[image: graph]

Let's find all the high degree vertices:

```
degree = AssociationThread[VertexList[graph] -> VertexDegree[graph]];

highDegree = Keys@Select[degree, GreaterThan[2]];
```

Now, we need a function that will tell us how many points are given to any other point, and the one-argument from of `Nearest` is just the thing:

```
nearest = Nearest[Normal@pointIndex]; 
within = (Curry[nearest][{All, #}]@*vertexCoordinates) &
```

Now let's choose a point:

```
RandomSeed[1337];
point = RandomChoice@pointIndex
(* 89 *)
```

Now we can find the nodes that are within a given radius of `point` and have degree greater than 2 with just an `Intersection`:

```
radius = 8;
qualifying = Intersection[highDegree, within[radius][point]]
(* {70, 80, 89} *)
```

Now we can show our points on the graph:

```
Show[
 HighlightGraph[graph, 
  Append[Thread[Style[qualifying, Green]], Style[point, Red]], 
  VertexSize -> Large],
 Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[vertexCoordinates@point, radius]}],
 PlotRange -> (MinMax /@ Transpose[points]), 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image: highlighted]

## Update #1

While this works fine for a small dataset, apparently `Graph` is a huge bottleneck for larger datasets like the one [linked in the comments below](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13cAPBWTnbdJohuINtaSHCP48NaHF7wEH). Happily for us, that step isn't really necessary, since we only need to compute the degree of each vertex, and that's very easy.

My first attempt constructed `edges` in exactly the same way, and then uses `CountsBy` twice to find the number of times that each point appears in either the first or second position in an edge:

```
degree = Merge[{CountsBy[edges, First], CountsBy[edges, Last]}, Total]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.50316, Null} *)
```

Ten seconds ain't bad, but there's an even easier and faster solution because the degree of a vertex is just the number of times it appears in the original `q1`. Since using `Lookup` to do a big batch of lookups in an association is faster than mapping it, I was able to get the time required to compute `degree` down to two seconds (and skip the step where we construct `edges` entirely, which took a couple more seconds).

```
degree = Counts[Lookup[pointIndex, data]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.07044, Null} *)
```

On my computer the whole computation was finished in under a minute, with about half the time taken up with the file import.

It's weird `Graph` is so dang slow, though.

## Update #2

It turns out that it's passing the `VertexCoordinates` option that slows things down so much. Without that, it only takes about a second!

```
graph = Graph[edges]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.12316, Null} *)
```

If I had to speculate, that option forces the routine to do some sort of layout or rendering that's very slow for largish numbers of points.

## Update 3

The issue is not `VertexCoordinates`, it's passing a list of rules as the argument. If you do an ordered list of points, it's much faster, suggesting that the current version uses rule replacement to assign the coordinates to each point in turn:

```
graph = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Values@coordinateIndex]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Alternatively, it turns out you can pass in a `Dispatch`ed list of rules (or association) and get good performance.

```
coordinateDispatch = Dispatch@coordinateIndex; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.12082, Null} *)

graph = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> coordinateDispatch]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.86843, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Where is 'coordinateIndex' defined?

Comment: Copied the wrong cell. Fixed.

Comment: How to replace the command "Curry[]"? I have Mathematica v11.

Comment: You can define your own as `Curry[f_][y_][x_] := f[x, y]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, again. But for a big network, the script has 'a bottleneck', ie Graph []. Details here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13cAPBWTnbdJohuINtaSHCP48NaHF7wEH?usp=sharing

Comment: One night calculation is ok but for several days may be a problem with RAM memory.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Using locators to specify a radius for each selected node:

```
qToV = AssociationThread[#, Range@Length @ #] & @ DeleteDuplicates[q1];
vToQ = Association @ KeyValueMap[#2 -> # &]@qToV;
vl = Values @ qToV;
el = UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[qToV /@ q1, 2];
gr = Graph[vl, el, VertexCoordinates -> Normal[vToQ], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", EdgeStyle -> Red, 
   VertexStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> Large];
vdGT2 = Select[VertexDegree[gr, #] > 2 &] @ vl;

Manipulate[Dynamic @ HighlightGraph[gr, 
   Join @@ {Function[c, 
       Style[Select[Norm[vToQ@c - vToQ@#] <= Norm[vToQ@c - locs[[c]]] &]@vdGT2, 
          Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], Opacity[1], Green]]] /@ centers, 
       Style[#, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Opacity[1], Purple]] & /@ centers}, 
   Prolog -> {Green, Dashed, Circle[vToQ[#], Norm[vToQ@# - locs[[#]]]] & /@ centers, 
     Text[Style["◼", show /. {True -> Orange, False -> White}, 
         FontSize -> show /. {True -> 14, False -> 1}], #] & /@ locs[[centers]]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 50, PlotRangeClipping -> False], 
 Dynamic @ Row[{Control@{{centers, {10, 43}}, vl, TogglerBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {5, Automatic}}, 
    If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
     Control[{{show, True, ""}, {True -> "Hide Locators", 
        False -> "Show Locators"}, ControlType -> Toggler, 
       Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5], FrameMargins -> 10}], ""]}, 
   Spacer[5]], 
 {{locs, 2 {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]} + # & /@ DeleteDuplicates[q1]}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
qToV = AssociationThread[#, Range@Length@#] &@DeleteDuplicates[q1];
vToQ = Association@KeyValueMap[#2 -> # &]@qToV;
vl = Values @ qToV;
el = UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[qToV /@ q1, 2];
gr = Graph[vl, el, VertexCoordinates -> Normal[vToQ], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", EdgeStyle -> Red, 
   VertexStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> Large];
vdGT2 = Select[VertexDegree[gr, #] > 2 &] @ vl;

Manipulate[HighlightGraph[gr, 
   {Style[Select[Norm[vToQ@center - vToQ@#] <= radii[[1]] &] @ vdGT2,
      Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Opacity[1], Blue]],
    Style[Select[radii[[1]] <= Norm[vToQ@center - vToQ@#] <= radii[[2]] &]@vdGT2,
      Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Opacity[1], Green]],
    Style[center, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Opacity[1], Purple]]}, 
   Prolog -> {FaceForm[], 
     EdgeForm[{Blue, Dashed}], Disk[vToQ[center], radii[[1]]],
     EdgeForm[{Green, Dashed}], Disk[vToQ[center], radii[[2]]]},
   ImagePadding -> 50, PlotRangeClipping -> False],
 {{center, 10}, vl, SetterBar, Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {5, Automatic}},
 {{radii, {4, 8}}, 0, 20, IntervalSlider[##, Method -> "Stop"] &,
    Appearance -> {"Paired", "Labeled"}, ImageSize -> 350},
 Alignment -> Center, TrackedSymbols :> {center, radii}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. What 'vToCoords' is? Calculations will be made for very large networks. This was just an example. There will be a definite set points 'points = RandomSample[q1, Floor[Length[q1]/10]]'. For each of these 'points' the number of 'specific nodes(degree greater than 2)' should be determined for e.g. r = {1,2,3,4,5, ...., 30}.

Answer (score -1):

**Thank you all for your help and comments!**

I think I found a very fast and simple 'script':

q1=Partition[q1, 2];

q2 = Map[Line@# &, q1];

pointX = {6534, 1050}; (*example*)

R = 12; (*example*)

k1 = Graphics[{Green, Thick, Dashed, Circle[pointX, R]}];

k2 = ListPlot[{pointX}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green, PointSize[.025]}];

k3 = ListPlot[Flatten[q1, 1], PlotStyle -> Black];

lines = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Opacity[0.7], q2}, ImageSize -> 500];

k6 = Show[lines, k1, k2, k3]

q3 = Select[
   q1, ((#[[1, 1]] - pointX[[1]])^2 + (#[[1, 2]] - 
         pointX[[2]])^2 <= (R)^2) &];

q4 = Select[
   q3, ((#[[2, 1]] - pointX[[1]])^2 + (#[[2, 2]] - 
         pointX[[2]])^2 <= (R)^2) &];

q88 = Map[Line@# &, q4];

k7 = Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.7], q88}, ImageSize -> 500];

k8 = Show[k6, k7]

q5 = Split[Sort[Flatten[q4, 1]]];

q6 = Select[q5, Length[#] >= 3 &];

k9 = ListPlot[q6[[All, 1]], 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, PointSize[.025]}];

Show[k8, k9]

Print["Solution ->  ", Length@q6]  (**Solution !!!!!!!!**)